# How do I create a class that stores objects of another class?

Tags: python, class, nameerror

There is a database that I work with, and for simplicity with queries to it, I wrote a module for convenient operation.

The request itself is divided into two parts: the request itself and its type (POST, GET, DEL, etc.)

```py
# Contains query types
class __request_type(Enum):
    NONE = 'NONE'
    POST = 'POST'
    GET  = 'GET'
    DEL  = 'DEL'

# The request itself is collected here
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class __request:
    request: str           # Request
    request_type: Enum = 0 # Request type (request_type: __request_type or Enum = __request_type.NONE doesn't work - NameError)
```

I want to create a class that will store frequently used queries for easy access to them.

For example:

```py
# Example of a container class
class Requests:
    GET_USER = __request('SQL REQUEST', __request_type.GET)
```

I tried many options, it all came down to one mistake:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programming\Python\bntu_schedule_v20\bot\utils\requests.py", line 18, in <module>
    class Request:
  File "d:\Programming\Python\bntu_schedule_v20\bot\utils\requests.py", line 19, in Request 
    GET_USER = __request('SQL REQUEST', __request_type.GET)
NameError: name '_Request__request' is not defined
```

An example of the record I'm aiming for:

```py
if Requests.GET_USER.request_type.value == __request_type.GET:
    ...
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how `__` at the start of a name triggers "name mangling"? https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=name%20mangling#id64

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @slothrop comment, the issue has been resolved.

The problem was that `__classname` was understood by Python as a "mangled" class. (read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=name%20mangling#i-try-to-use-spam-and-i-get-an-error-about-someclassname-spam))

> Variable names with double leading underscores are “mangled” to provide a simple but effective way to define class private variables. Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with any leading underscores stripped.

This means that the solution to the problem will be as follows:

```py
class request_type(Enum):
    NONE = 'NONE'
    POST = 'POST'
    GET  = 'GET'
    DEL  = 'DEL'


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class request:
    request: str
    request_type: Enum = request_type.NONE


class Requests:
    GET_USER = request('SQL REQUEST', request_type.GET)

print(f'Requests.GET_USER: {Requests.GET_USER}')
print(f'Requests.GET_USER.request: {Requests.GET_USER.request}')
print(f'Requests.GET_USER.request_type: {Requests.GET_USER.request_type}')
```

Result:

```py
Requests.GET_USER: request(request='SQL REQUEST', request_type=<request_type.GET: 'GET'>)
Requests.GET_USER.request: SQL REQUEST
Requests.GET_USER.request_type: request_type.GET
```